# socket.emit - Event name [socket.io]

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I use:

**Server:**

```
socket.emit('news', 'ZZZ');
```

**Client:**

```
socket.on('news', function (data) {
    document.querySelector('#gamesList').innerHTML = data;
});
```

***All is working!***

But if i change event name to a "temp":

**Server:**

```
socket.emit('temp', 'ZZZ');
```

**Client:**

```
socket.on('temp', function (data) {
    document.querySelector('#gamesList').innerHTML = data;
});
```

It's not working! Why? I can't use my own event names?

Thank in advance!

Comment: Maybe if you change 'temo' to 'temp' on the receiving side ?

Comment: and the 'temo' is not a typo, right?

Comment: "'temo' to 'temp'" in code it's correct. I make i mistake here.

Comment: You should debug to see what happens. You might have a cache problem client side for example.

Comment: I use Symfony 2. I may clear my cache and then use "emit". I try this now...

Comment: LOL. Guys, it's browser cache. Clearing Firefox cache -> all working.

Comment: you should put your findings as answer and accept the same for others to use.

Comment: Chirag Jain, Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You can answer 12/7/2013 10:18:09 PM. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead.


Let's wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear your browser's cache.

If you use the "Symfony 2 Framework", correctly use "assetic".